# Convert Data Table with Column Names to JSON

Tags: c#, json

Currently I am getting a data table from a SQL SP wherein one of the column has the value for the fields that I am looking for.

For example:

```
 [{
    "Date": "2018-04-30",
    "Office_ID": "0001",
    "Metric_Name": "Hours_Worked",
    "Actual_Value": "25",
    "Goal_Value": "100",
    "Actual_Percent": "25%",
    "Goal_Percent": "50%",
    "Actual_Points": "1",
    "Goal_Points": "5"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2018-04-30",
    "Office_ID": "0001",
    "Metric_Name": "Projects_Worked",
    "Actual_Value": "5",
    "Goal_Value": "10",
    "Actual_Percent": "50%",
    "Goal_Percent": "50%",
    "Actual_Points": "5",
    "Goal_Points": "5"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2018-04-30",
    "Office_ID": "0002",
    "Metric_Name": "Hours_Worked",
    "Actual_Value": "75",
    "Goal_Value": "100",
    "Actual_Percent": "75%",
    "Goal_Percent": "50%",
    "Actual_Points": "5",
    "Goal_Points": "5"
  },
  {
    "Date": "2018-04-30",
    "Office_ID": "0002",
    "Metric_Name": "Projects_Worked",
    "Actual_Value": "10",
    "Goal_Value": "10",
    "Actual_Percent": "100%",
    "Goal_Percent": "50%",
    "Actual_Points": "5",
    "Goal_Points": "5"
  }]
```

I want to use the value in the Metric_Name Field as a field name itself and tag all the metric information to it. I am trying to get to a JSON like below:

```
[{"Office_ID": "0001",
  "Date": "2018-04-30",
  "Hours_Worked": {"Actual_Value": "25",
                   "Goal_Value": "100",
                   "Actual_Percent": "25%",
                   "Goal_Percent": "50%",
                   "Actual_Points": "1",
                   "Goal_Points": "5"
                  },
  "Projects_Worked": {"Actual_Value": "5",
                      "Goal_Value": "10",
                      "Actual_Percent": "50%",
                      "Goal_Percent": "50%",
                      "Actual_Points": "5",
                      "Goal_Points": "5"
                     }
 },
 {"Office_ID": "0002",
  "Date": "2018-04-30",
  "Hours_Worked": {"Actual_Value": "75",
                   "Goal_Value": "100",
                   "Actual_Percent": "75%",
                   "Goal_Percent": "50%",
                   "Actual_Points": "5",
                   "Goal_Points": "5"
                  },
  "Projects_Worked": {"Actual_Value": "10",
                      "Goal_Value": "10",
                      "Actual_Percent": "100%",
                      "Goal_Percent": "50%",
                      "Actual_Points": "5",
                      "Goal_Points": "5"
                     }
 }]
```

I am trying to implement this in C#. Hopefully this is something which is possible.

Currently I am using a workaround to loop over all the values and do something like below wherein I have defined a PerformanceModel with a field for each metric values:

```
 foreach (var item in result.Select( x=>x.Office_ID).Distinct())
            {
                PerformanceModel _performancemetric = new PerformanceModel();
                foreach (var metric in result.Where(y => y.Office_ID == item))
                {
                    _performancemetric.Office_ID = metric.Office_ID;
                    _performancemetric.Date = metric.Date;
                    switch(metric.Metric_Name)
                    {
                        case "Hours_Worked":
                            _performancemetric.Hours_Worked_Actual_Value = Int32.Parse(metric.Actual_Value,0);
                            _performancemetric.Hours_Worked_Goal_Value = Int32.Parse(metric.Goal_Value,0);
                            _performancemetric.Hours_Worked_Goal_Point = metric.Goal_Points;
                            _performancemetric.Hours_Worked_Actual_Point = metric.Actual_Points;
                            _performancemetric.Hours_Worked_Goal_Percent = metric.Goal_Percent;
                            _performancemetric.Hours_Worked_Actual_Percent = metric.Actual_Percent;
                            break;
                        case "Projects_Worked":
                            _performancemetric.Projects_Worked_Actual_Value = Int32.Parse(metric.Actual_Value,0);
                            _performancemetric.Projects_Worked_Goal_Value = Int32.Parse(metric.Goal_Value,0);
                            _performancemetric.Projects_Worked_Goal_Point = metric.Goal_Points;
                            _performancemetric.Projects_Worked_Actual_Point = metric.Actual_Points;
                            _performancemetric.Projects_Worked_Goal_Percent = metric.Goal_Percent;
                            _performancemetric.Projects_Worked_Actual_Percent = metric.Actual_Percent;
                            break;
                    }
                }
 _performancelist.Add(_performancemetric);
        }
```

But I hope there is a better way to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: Ok so what have you tried already?  We are not a code writing service.

Comment: `I am trying to get to a JSON like below`  can you show the code from those efforts, or is that something you want the code faerie to bring?  Also, there are some 35,000 posts here already for *serialise datatable to json*

Comment: My bad. I added what I am currently doing as a workaround. The other options/solutions I tried were so far off that they were not even worth mentioning.

Comment: Will there only ever be the two fields?  `Hours_Worked` and `Projects_Worked`?

Comment: It is around 4 fields but yes it is a fixed number of known fields. I included only 2 for simplicity.

Comment: instead of `foreach (var item in result.Select( x=>x.Office_ID).Distinct())` you probably need something like `foreach (var group in result.GroupBy(x => x.Office_ID))` and `foreach (var metric in group)`

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is:

1. Deserialize this JSON thanks to NewtonSoft.JSON (you can get it via NuGet Package Manager).
2. Data processing on your objects.
3. Serialize back the resulting object as JSON.

Example on a smaller snippet:

```
public class Container
{
    public DateTime Date { get; }
    public string OfficeId { get; }
    public string Metric_Name { get; }

    // the following is when you want to add nested objects in your json
    public AContent AContent { get; }

    // ...

    public class AContent
    {
        // whatever you want
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new object from the json.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="json">The json as a string.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Container FromJson(string json)
    {
        try
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(json);
        }
        catch (JsonException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Transforms this to a json string
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string ToJson()
    {
        try
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

By the way I see That your JSON is as a List. So you may want to serialize a List directly, such as:

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Container>>(json);
```